# Circle and ellipse intersection points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We have system of two equations:

$$x^2+y+y^2=4$$

$$x^2+xy+y^2=3$$

I can not find points of intersection of these two curves (just points of intersection) using basic construction tools - ruler and compass. Please help.

Comment: Three of the intersection points involve roots of an irreducible cubic, so you're not going to be able to construct them using ruler and compass (at least, assuming that by "ruler" you meant "straightedge").

Comment: Thank you Roger! Yes one of them is 2: -1, other 3 are hard to find. But I can't understand why two quadratic intersections are not construable geometrically.

Comment: As @rogeri mentioned, in general finding the intersections involves solving a cubic equation, not all of which are constructible. IIRC, this is one of the applications that motivated the study of how to solve cubics.

Comment: Thank you AMD! I was under impression that ellipse can be constructed without "string" . How do those point become cubical?

Comment: If you just combine the two equations you have to solve a quartic. A different solution method involves finding a linear combination of the two equations that produces a degenerate conic, which then reduces the two-conic intersection problem to that of intersecting a conic with a pair of lines. A cubic equation arises in finding the coefficients of the linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

The intersections are the roots of a quartic. To see this, solve the first equation for $x^2$ and substitute into the second, giving
$$4-y-y^2+y\sqrt{4-y-y^2}+y^2=3,$$
or
$$y^2(4-y-y^2) = y-1.$$
Collecting terms and simplifying gives a quartic one of whose roots is $y=-1$. The remaining cubic is irreducible with three real roots.